# TypeScript boolean generic ternary opearator error

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

In this code:

```
function formField<Multiple extends boolean>(multiple: Multiple, onChange: (newValue: Multiple extends true ? string[] : string) => void) {
  if (multiple) {
    // Error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Multiple extends true ? string[] : string'.
    onChange(["Hello, World!"]);
  } else {
    // TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Multiple extends true ? string[] : string'.
    onChange("Hello, World!");
  }
}
```

The idea is having `multiple` should result in a call to `onChange` with a `string[]`, otherwise with `string`

There is an error when invoking `onChange` despite providing them with the right argument types. How can I fix this error and why does it occur?

I would prefer to never cast in the solution.

Comment: Ternary type detection might not be better than argument type detection. Why won't you just detection the argument type in `onChange` ?

Comment: How does that work? @Horsing

Comment: Suppose you have an `onChange: (args: string[]|string) => void`, check arguments type in your real `onChange` function as : `args instanceof Array`. Then do what ever you want.

Comment: The compiler cannot reason about generic conditional types (the term "conditional type" is conventional and preferred over "ternary operator") so it complains; the only way around this is essentially a type assertion (the term "type assertion" is conventional and preferred over "cast"); see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write this up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You can use a discriminated union: https://tsplay.dev/NlllxN

Comment: @pink if they accept that will you include a bit in your answer about why the OP's code doesn't work?

Comment: @jcalz Will do; shall I paraphrase your comment then?

Comment: Yeah sure (unless you have a better explanation or some other source).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that narrowing the variable doesn't narrow the type parameter. Ideally, `if (multiple) {` should also narrow `Multiple` to be `true`. However, we see that it hasn't changed:

```
if (multiple) {
    multiple
//  ^? Multiple extends boolean
}
```

[image]

Since it's still of type `Multiple`, `onChange`'s type is still `(newValue: Multiple extends true ? string[] : string) => void`. To put it in another way, the compiler can't really reason about generic conditional types (as mentioned by jcalz [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947368/typescript-boolean-generic-ternary-opearator-error#comment133959808_75947368)).

This isn't really the place to use conditional types anyways. I often see conditional types being (ab)used like this, which can (and should) be solved with discriminated unions or overloads. In this case, I believe you should use discriminated unions since they allow for proper narrowing as you originally wanted:

```
function formField(...[multiple, onChange]: [true, (newValue: string[]) => void] | [false, (newValue: string) => void]) {
  if (multiple) {
    onChange(["Hello, World!"]); // okay
  } else {
    onChange("Hello, World!");   // okay
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOAnAtgMRgUwDYAmAFAHRkDa6IesADnjgDSIIDCAFgIZgDmOAugC5E5KKhBNERMDgDuANU54JwgM5iYvcvwCUiALwA+RADc4MAv0QAfEcCWrJ0uYuU41G3nqOnzlvQDeALAAUIiIMMBSVDQw9DiBoeHhbFy8OETkAEQAEvh4cMwA6miEAIRZugDcSYgAvoj4jojBYcmp3HxEufmFiCWo5Vk6NW11oeMhQA)